# Weblogic 12c scripts to create a domain

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

Good day,

I am trying to create a weblogic domain through a script, but when I try to executes a script, I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class:

Answer (score 0):

I meant to comment but it says I have to have "**50 reputation**. But anyway, have you declared the PATH variable correctly?

Comment: Yes, the path variable looks okay, and what is very weird here, it does not give me a specific class that has an issue. Error: Could not find or load main class:

Comment: Could you please list down the chronology of tasks you performed until encountering this error?

Comment: Hi, 
I am trying to run this script that creates a domain and managed servers:
#!/bin/sh

BASE_DIR=`dirname $0`

. $BASE_DIR/config.sh
             EXECUTION
if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ]; then
    echo setup SSH
    sh $BASE_DIR/ssh/ssh_auth.sh
fi;
echo $DOMAIN_EXISTS
if [ "$DOMAIN_EXISTS" == "false" ]; then
        sh $BASE_DIR/domain/create-domain.sh
fi;

sh $BASE_DIR/ics/createXXX.sh

if [ ! -d $DOMAIN_DIR=/etc ]; then
        echo setup logging
        sh $BASE_DIR/logging.sh
fi;

Comment: This script calls two script:
1 .createICS.sh
2.create-domain.sh if it does not exist. 
CREATEXXX.SH looks like this:
echo Copy temp files

cp  $BASE_DIR/c2sConfigtatis_cms /tmp/c2sConfigtatis_cms
cp  $BASE_DIR/c2sSecrettatis_cms /tmp/c2sSecrettatis_cms
cp  $BASE_DIR/../config.py.properties /tmp/
chmod +x $SCRIPT_FILE

if [ -z $BEA_HOME ]; then
    echo Setting BEA_HOME to /opt/oracle/Middleware
    BEA_HOME/opt/oracle/Middleware
fi;

Comment: echo Create Local Executing
$BEA_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh $SCRIPT_FILE >> $LOG_FILE
#$BEA_HOME/common/bin/wlst.sh $SCRIPT_FILE -loadProperties /tmp/config.py.properties
#java weblogic.WLST $SCRIPT_FILE > $LOG_FILE
if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
        echo Something went wrong with $TMP_SCRIPT
        exit 2;
fi;
The error produced at this "echo Create Local Executing $CREATE_SCRIPT" when is trying to reference to $BEA_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh $SCRIPT_FILE >> $LOG_FILE.